# merge failing on branch reverted to previous commit

Tags: git

I was working on a feature branch yesterday and merged with develop. The update blocked me on something so I checked out a previous commit of my branch. I then did more commits from that point. Today I want to merge into develop again to grab the changes that previously blocked me but my branch thinks its up to date with develop though I can see from the code that it's not. I've merged another feature branch into develop and tried again to see if the new develop ref would help but when I try to merge develop into my feature branch I see :

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy
1 file changed...
```

So this is picking up the change from the other branch but not from the one I'm interested in. Do I need to run the merge with a strategy other then recursive?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Comment: I think you may have made some commits not on any branch (by committing on top of a commit other than the branch head). These stranded commits cannot be merged and are tricky to get back. You may have to look up their refs and cherry pick them onto a new branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Vality said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136948/merge-failing-on-branch-reverted-to-previous-commit#comment39127101_25136948), this:

> so I checked out a previous commit of my branch. I then did more commits from that point.

suggests that you created an anonymous branch (on a "detached HEAD"), whose commits are now found only in the reflog.

To get them back, use `git reflog` to display a list of "things done that caused `HEAD` to change".  In the log, you will see things like:

```
d1574b8 HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving
     from 11d9593a8479fb8b069eb81ff4368637186122bb to master
11d9593 HEAD@{16}: commit: example
9c4ea50 HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from master to HEAD~3
```

The values like `11d9593` (or the long version of it) are raw SHA-1s; the `HEAD@{number}` fields are short-hand ways (sometimes not that short) to spell the SHA-1s.  The numbers inside the braces change—they go up, `HEAD@{0}` is the most recent—as you do various operations on `HEAD`, such as `git checkout` or `git commit`, but the SHA-1s are permanent.<sup>1</sup>

If you want to recover a commit, such as the one I made called `example` above, you can start by giving it a name, so that you won't have to remember its number, and it won't get deleted after the reflog entry expires.  For the name, you can use a branch:

```
git branch recovered-as-branch 11d9593
```

or a tag:

```
git tag recovered-as-tag 11d9593
```

(use any name you like; note that `recovered-as-whatever` is a terrible name, except when being used as an example).

The difference here is that if you make it a branch, you can use `git checkout` to get on it and add more commits, and the branch name will move forward with those new commits, just like any other branch; if you make it a tag, you can still do `git checkout` on it, but you'll be back in that "detached HEAD" mode again, so if you make more commits, they will be found only in the reflog, just like the situation you got into this time.  (There's nothing wrong with that, and in fact, there are some tricks you can do that are actually easier in this "detached HEAD" mode.  This is how the `git rebase` interactive-rebase script does its thing, for instance.  The main problem with detached HEAD mode is that it's easy to forget stuff, if you forget that you're in it.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, permanent until the reflog entry itself expires and the commit is "garbage-collected".  Reflog entries like `HEAD@{42}` expire in 30 to 90 days by default, though you can change this setting in your git configuration.